# Get names of private methods of AppKit classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, private

I have been struggling with this for some time now.

There have been many times I wanted to change something minor in a control, but I had to redraw the entire thing just to adjust it. 
Like a NSPathControl, I just wanted to change the background of the Path Control, I ended up creating a whole new control just for that small adjustment...

Apple uses private methods, like the following:

```
- (void)_drawContextMenuHighlightForIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes clipRect:(NSRect)rect;
```

I have found this in a Stackoverflow-Post.

How should I know about these?
I don't think they are meant to be public, but this is just WAY easier.
Where do these people know this from?
Are there any references? I wouldn't need to know any source code, I would only have to know the names of the private methods.

So my question, how can I get the names of private methods of AppKit classes?

Thanks

Comment: Note that changing the internals of the AppKit (or any other system framework) is generally rife with problems and runs the risk of rejection from the App Store.  That stuff is private for a reason.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'll avoid this whenever it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private class method names can be obtained using [Obj-C runtime functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). To get a list of methods of a class you can do something like:

```
unsigned int methodCount;
Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(theClass, &methodCount);
for (int i = 0; i < methodCount; i++) {
    Method method = methods[i];
    NSString *methodName = NSStringFromSelector(method_getName(method));
    // collect name in an array or print it.
}
free(methods);
```

There is also a handy terminal tool that does this for you called [class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/).

Answer (score 1):

you query the runtime for methods/properties/variables a class has or you use a handy tool (DDDump) from github that does this at runtime by adding a category on NSObject

```
NSLog(@"%@", [obj dump]);
```

---

not requested but also really useful in that context is the **NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled** environment variable, which -when YES- allows you to see any dispatching done!

---

oh and getting all notifications is always a good idea too :)